# Correct scheme to persistently update a model of a collection in Backbone app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In Backbone terms, What is the correct scheme to persistently update a model which is a member of a collection and reperesented in the user interface?

By utilising a DOM event and method in the view.

Then grabbing the id of the element to be processed by from the event objects, eg. from click.

finding the model in the collection, by findWhere.

Then using set on the model changing attributes.

Then using save() on the model to update the model on server side and client side.

But one may need to wait for success on server side process and only then update the client side model and collection. This can be done by {wait: true} in order to wait server response, but does this mean if and only if the server process succeeds to persist the model in the db this attributes will be set in the client side model. What if it fails on server side what about the preceding lines that set() the model found.

Also adding the new state of the model into the collection.

Lastly, re-rendering the view with the new state of the collection.

Comment: calling `model.save()`? can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a little bit like you may be wanting 2-way data binding.

[Backbone.Stickit](http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/) is a great plugin for that.

Comment: I do not understand what the {wait:true} option provide for a model set with new attribute values. It was already set in the previous lines before the save includes this option.

Comment: Is the model instance created added to the client side collection if and only if the server side addition successful?

Comment: Is wait:true only useful if new attributes, not attribute values only, to be added to the model should be wait successful server response?

Comment: a really quick, really rough example that automatically saves the models changes via PATCH request when its changed. http://jsbin.com/hecimuqeze/3/edit?html,js,console,output